# Mixed QR code with static text and a URL

Tags: url, qr-code

I am trying to create a QR code with both static text and a URL. The static text is 23 characters long and must be first in the code. I can add the URL after the text, and my phone scanning tool recognizes it as a URL, but I need it to automatically launch the URL when scanned. Basically to ignore the first 23 digits. Is there a delimiter I can use to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

The QRCode specification says nothing about the contents it can have, so you are  limited to how the scanners handle the input. You can find a good description of the de-facto contents a QRcode can have on the [zxing lib wiki](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/wiki/Barcode-Contents) and some nice examples [on this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26738158/1167210).

Basically you can either have a URL (which might have your static text as a parameter to be shown on the page, think `http://example.com?text=yourContent`), or a text with the URL on the end - in which case you are scanner-implementation dependent, but will probably end up with wrong results. There is no default delimiter.

Comment: Having the URL as the last line of text in the QR Code text, separated by a linefeed, is actually working on my iPhone.  I did not understand your answer until I posted my answer, which is essentially the same answer.  Example code would be ```qrcodeText = "My sample text\nhttps://www.example.com"``` I would like to know if this works with other phones like Android.

Answer (score 0):

If you reverse the order, it will work, at least with iphone;
"www.example.com-Text"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).