# QR Code - multiple actions

Tags: wifi, action, qr-code

Is there a way to create multiple actions for a QR Code ?

The goal would be to scan the QR code and executes thoses actions :

1. Connect to WIFI
2. Go to specific URL

I could do those 2 actions with 2 QR Code but it will be easier to only have one

Comment: Hi... Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @HaydarC. : Unfortunately no and I didn't follow up sorry. If you find a way to do it, please post it here as an answer

Answer (score 0):

You can't.
Simply because the scanner can't support it and will decode it as a simple text (or even crash!).
See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26738158/4593527) if you want to know what datatypes you can put in qr-codes. (some apps won't even support all of these)

Answer (score -1):

What operating system are you talking about?

In general, you can extract the text from the QR code (in your case most propably an URL) and do whatever you want with that text.

Under Ubuntu Linux, for example, you could use `zbarimg` from the *zbar-tools* package to extract the text from  you can get the URL from the qrcode using:

```
URL=$(zbarimg --raw --quiet QRCODE.png)
```

Comment: Acutally, it is not about coding. I want my user to scan the QR code which will connect him to a specific network and also open a new page with a specific URL (my website)