# IOS - Generate QR codes with different types

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

Using the following swift code I could generate a QR code as shown in figure A.
import UIKit

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var qrImageView: UIImageView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    }

    func generateQRCode(from string: String) -> UIImage? {
        let data = string.data(using: String.Encoding.ascii)


        if let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIQRCodeGenerator") {
            filter.setValue(data, forKey: "inputMessage")
            let transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 3, y: 3)

            if let output = filter.outputImage?.transformed(by: transform) {
                return UIImage(ciImage: output)
            }
        }

        return nil
    }
    @IBAction func generateQRAction(_ sender: Any) {
           let image = generateQRCode(from: "karthik +91993123333 karthikeyan.cpp@gmail.com trichy robotics")

            qrImageView.image = image
    }


}
```

Figure A:
[image]

If I scan this QR code through iPhone camera, I get a push notification, touching on that notification takes me to call that hard coded phone number.

[image]

Note that the generated QR code with phone number is of type calling the number.

How can I create QR codes with different types like,

- SMS content
- Adding to phone contact
- Compose email.

Touching on that notification after scanning our generated QR code should allow me to perform the above mentioned stuffs.

For example:
[image]

I know this is possible, but don't know how to achieve this.
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: CIFilter takes data for input message then I guess you can directly convert required thing to data and try.

Comment: You can check [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19900835/qr-code-possible-data-types-or-standards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19900835/qr-code-possible-data-types-or-standards)

Comment: Check this website out: https://www.the-qrcode-generator.com/